# Swift - How call UIVIewController from a Button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewCell` (.xib) and in this cell i have a Button, When pressed the button i would like to open a `UIViewController`.

[image]

The icon is my button

In my `TableViewController`:

```
class DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
...

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell

...
    return cell
}
```

and my `CustomCell` class:

```
class HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //how open a UIViewController (xib or main.storyboard)?
    }
    ...
```

How open a `UIViewController` (xib or main.storyboard)?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using segue or pushViewController?

Comment: to open DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController I use segue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `delegate` pattern for this use case,

Your `tableViewCell`:

```
protocol HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didButtonPressed()
}

class HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {
       delegate?.didButtonPressed()
    }
}
```

Your `ViewController`:

```
class DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

extension DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController: HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCellDelegate {

      func didButtonPressed() {
          // Push or present your view controller
      }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: still works in swift 5. Just mind that instead of "Bundle.main.loadNibNamed" use "tableView.dequeueReusableCell"

Answer (score 4):

You need to add UIButton action in `cellForRowAt` method like below:

```
cell.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOpenCaseTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Add UIButton Action in DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController ViewController like below:

```
@objc func btnOpenCaseTapped() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifire", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work this, value of type 'HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell' has no member 'performSegue'

Comment: compiler show error: Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'addTarget' . When I use delegate pattern works . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {

       let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your view controller identifier") as! your vc 
       self.present(vc,animated:true,completion: nil)
    }
```

try this hope it may help.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but compiler returns: Value of type 'HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell' has no member 'present'

Comment: oh yes... its tableview cell hmm .. and tableview cell has niether present nor segue.. i think you can make button action method in DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController rather than in cell class.. then both seugue and present will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare IBAction of button in cellForRowAtIndexPath itself.

Here in your code....

```
class DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HistoricoClienteServidorTableViewCell
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(yourButtonTapMethod:), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func yourButtonTapMethod(sender:UIButton){
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let controllerInstance = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
        "ControllerStoryBoardIdentifier") as! YourControllerName
    self.sharedCalss.creatingNewTrip = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerInstance, animated: true)
}
}
```

Button tap action method should implement in DetalhaConsultaServidorViewController itself.